# Using high resolution sprites in unity mobile game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Friends, I am developing a 2d game in unity, but I use 8k resolution photos in the game.
Do you think there would be any problems because the photos are 8k.If you have suggestions, what is it, thanks in advance

I mean, problems such as not working on lower device models or the device not supporting the game may occur.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the problems that may occur are performance related. It might be wise to make sure that Unity can properly compress those textures.

Here are a couple of resources that you may find useful:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportingTextures.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0DN9P8e7dc